# Hibernate Search in Spring Boot integration test problem

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, hibernate-search

I'm using **Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE** and **Hibernate Search 5.10.8.Final**.

I have a problem with Hibernate Search in my integration test in Spring Boot.

Integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class FindBookE2ETest {

    private String HTTP_LOCALHOST = "http://localhost:";

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    @Sql({"/book/book.sql"})
    public void findBookByLanguageTest() {
        ResponseEntity<List<BookDTO>> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(HTTP_LOCALHOST + port + "/findBooks/ENG/language", HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<BookDTO>>() {});
        assertThat(exchange.getStatusCode().value()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        assertThat(exchange.getBody()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(exchange.getBody().get(0).getLanguage()).isEqualTo("ENG");
    }
}
```

In **classpath:application-test.properties** I have only **spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never**

Implementation of Hibernate Search

```
@Transactional
@Service("bookService")
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

     private List<Book> searchBookByLanguage(String value) {
        List<Book> booksByLanguages = bookRepository.findBooksByLanguages(value); //for debug test purpose
        System.out.println("book from repo: " + booksByLanguages.size()); //for debug test purpose

        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder()
                .forEntity(Book.class)
                .get();

        Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder
                .keyword()
                .onFields("language")
                .matching(value)
                .createQuery();
        FullTextQuery jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Book.class);
        List<Book>  resultList = jpaQuery.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }

    ///rest of the code
}
```

Under **src/main/resource** I have **data.sql** file. Under **test/resource** I have sql files for each tests.

My problem is that.
When I run whole application everything works ok, but in integration test no. In findBookByLanguageTest() hibernate search does not return any values (bookRepository.findBooksByLanguages() returns) and I do not why. Maybe there is configuration problem?

I commented **spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never** in test properties and I got error that sql script in my test can not insert data because  (I do not know why) Spring get data from data.sql under src/main/reource/data.sql but this file is not in "test" section. So I commented sql annotation above my test as well so with this configuration:

**#spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never** in **classpath:application-test.properties**

and

```
    @Test
//    @Sql({"/book/book.sql"})
    public void findBookByLanguageTest() {
        ResponseEntity<List<BookDTO>> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(HTTP_LOCALHOST + port + "/findBooks/ENG/language", HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<BookDTO>>() {});
        assertThat(exchange.getStatusCode().value()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        assertThat(exchange.getBody()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(exchange.getBody().get(0).getLanguage()).isEqualTo("ENG");
    }
```

my test is working.

Someone knows what is the problem with my configuration? I want to separate my tests from data.sql and to have sql script for each test.
Maybe there is a problem with EntityManager?

**** **Edit after @yrodiere response** ****

I modified my **FindBookE2ETest** and now it looks like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class FindBookE2ETest {

    private String HTTP_LOCALHOST = "http://localhost:";

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        entityManager = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Test
    @Sql({"/book/book.sql"})
    public void findBookByLanguageTest() {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();

        ResponseEntity<List<BookDTO>> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(HTTP_LOCALHOST + port + "/findBooks/ENG/language", HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<BookDTO>>() {});
        assertThat(exchange.getStatusCode().value()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        assertThat(exchange.getBody()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(exchange.getBody().get(0).getLanguage()).isEqualTo("ENG");
    }
}
```

Now everything is working. Thx.

Comment: I'm surprised that you managed to get the test working at all. Do you take care of executing the [mass indexer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-massindexer) somewhere? For initialization, just inserting data in your database through SQL commands is not enough for Hibernate Search, because you bypassed Hibernate ORM: you also need to extract that data from the database and index it, and that's what the mass indexer is for.

Comment: Thx @yrodiere I forgot about it.